# Где могут храниться редиректы сайтов?

Tags: linux, ssh, редирект

Есть много доменов, все они перекидывают на один сайт.
Как отключить это?

Человек что настраивал всё это дело не выходит на связь, сказал что дело в каком-то SSH или ещё чем-то, в панели хостинга нет никаких редиректов и переходов, меняю по FTP файлы сайта, но безрезультатно, ничего не меняется.

Все домены:
http://bigbarabum.ru
http://91.192.60.30/
http://incoclub.com/

Дико запутанная история, распутать никак не могу. Если поможете, будет здорово

Comment: то есть все что я делаю на FTP никак не отражается на сайте...

Comment: `.htaccess` и файл конфигурации web-сервера проверяли?

Comment: Вот, кстати, полезная ссылка о том, как узнать актуальное расположение главного файла конфигурации: http://commanigy.com/blog/2011/6/8/finding-apache-configuration-file-httpd-conf-location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас два сайта в Липецке (91.192.60.0 и icoclub.com), один в Москве на jino (bigbarabum.ru). Посмотрите на https://2ip.ru/whois/

Так что к какому бы из двух хостингов у вас ни был доступ сейчас, проблема на хостинге нерешаемая. Существуют две физические копии сайта в разных местах.